# Apache VirtualHosts: two subdomain configurations possible?

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, document-root

At present, I have the following VirtualHost configuration set up on my Apache 2.4 server (running EasyPHP):

```bash
## Local domain access
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.local *.*.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/var/www/%-2/public_html"
    <Directory "D:/var/www/*/public_html">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Essentially, this maps `{domain}.local` and `{sub}.{domain}.local` to the `{domain}`s document root - the reason it's done this way is due to the fact that I primarily develop with Laravel, and make good use of [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing).

However, there are certain situations whereby I need to have the subdomain-request point to another directory in the domain's document-root parent, thus calling up a different application with its own document root.

With the above VirtualHost configuration, requesting *test.example.local* will serve up the document root at `D:\var\www\example\public_html`.

What additions or changes can I make to this configuration to allow the above example to serve `D:\var\www\example\test\public_html` instead, but only if the `test` directory exists?

Comment: You define separate virtual hosts for that. This allows to use literal path specifications. Note however that using separate host names (sometimes called "sub domains") may result in issues with security precautions the browsers apply if you are using https (which you certainly should).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that may be the case. The question then becomes one about conflict - how will Apache be able to determine which virtual host to use? Which one do I define first?

Comment: Or are you saying that I'd need to define a host for each one specifically?

Comment: As documented the first defined virtual host is used as a fallback. Apart from that the order is not important. The matching host is chosen by the `HOST` header present in the http request. That simply is how name based virtual hosts work. Note: _"name based virtual hosts"_, not address based virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Yes, you define a separate virtual host for each hostname. You can include a shared configuration file for those definitions identical to all of them. But the host definitions themselves should be separate.

Comment: Okay, so I've tested by creating a static virtual host (no `VirtualDocumentRoot`), and it turns out I need to place this above the configuration I'm already using. Apache ignores it otherwise. Was hoping for a "catch-all if this directory exists" kinda thing - guessing that's not possible.

Comment: Certainly a catch all is possible, I mentioned that above. But you should change your point of view. Skip thinking file system based. An http server is meant to work on URLs, not on file paths.

Comment: Okay, I get that, but the issue is that this concept primarily revolves around the file-system, so I would then assume that what I'm looking for is not possible... (Note: I'm not an Apache guru - I just configure it until it works according to the intent; past that, I'm a tad 'blind'.)

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is with defining separate hosts. It is maybe 5 lines for each. That's all, and it is static. If you really have such a huge amount that this appears not to be possible, then take a look at database based "mass virtual hosting". But frankly, this reads like you are making en elephant out of a moskito. _Just do it_.

Comment: Haha, okay then - I will. Would have been great if it was a possibility.

Comment: Actually this might be possible file system based... not exactly common and how things are meant to be used, but why not? You define a single catch all host and add rewriting rules evaluating the `HOST` header of the request. That way you can easily internally rewrite requests, so map them onto file system folders depending on whether those exist or not. Take a look at the documentation of apaches rewriting module. It has really good examples for such conditionals (`RewriteCond`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I figured that I shouldn't make things complicated ([elephant/mosquito metaphor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235788/apache-virtualhosts-two-subdomain-configurations-possible#comment62001173_37235788)), but should still comply with the [DRY principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) so that I don't have a huge mess of exceptions in my virtual host configuration file - at the end of the day, this gets quite exhausting, and difficult to maintain.

As such, I've opted to use Apache's `mod_macro` module - this needs to be explicitly enabled.

The result is this:

```bash
# Macro LocalSub
# For specific *.*.local subdomains that require their own DIRECTORY_ROOT
<Macro LocalSub $sub $domain>
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        ServerName $sub.$domain.local
        DocumentRoot "D:/var/www/$domain/$sub/public_html"
        <Directory "D:/var/www/$domain/$sub/public_html">
            Require all granted
            Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

# Specific subdomain Macro usage
Use LocalSub assets example
Use LocalSub images01 mydomain
Use LocalSub images02 mydomain

# Fallback to *.local and *.*.local (points to the same DOCUMENT_ROOT)
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.local *.*.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/var/www/%-2/public_html"
    <Directory "D:/var/www/*/public_html">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is better than the [`mod_rewrite` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235788/apache-virtualhosts-two-subdomain-configurations-possible#comment62001237_37235788) in the `VirtualHost` context as this method allows the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to be set correctly.

At the end of the day, trying to get Apache to automate everything for me, and thus bending to my very specific wills, is not the way to go - so a little manual overriding does the trick, whilst keeping everything DRY.

This could be taken a step further by also 'macrofying' `<Directory>`:

```bash
# Macro Directory
# Default Directory configuration on a per-vhost basis
<Macro Directory $dir>
    <Directory "D:/var/www/$dir/public_html">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</Macro>

# Macro LocalSub
# For specific *.*.local subdomains that require their own DIRECTORY_ROOT
<Macro LocalSub $sub $domain>
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        ServerName $sub.$domain.local
        DocumentRoot "D:/var/www/$domain/$sub/public_html"
        Use Directory $domain/$sub
    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

# Specific subdomain Macro usage
Use LocalSub assets example
Use LocalSub images01 mydomain
Use LocalSub images02 mydomain

# Fallback to *.local and *.*.local (points to the same DOCUMENT_ROOT)
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.local *.*.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/var/www/%-2/public_html"
    Use Directory *
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning Mike,

I suggest creating separate virtual hosts

```
## Local domain access
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.*.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:\var\www\example\test\public_html"
    <Directory "D:\var\www\example\test\public_html">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

## Local domain access
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:\var\www\example\public_html"
    <Directory "D:\var\www\example\public_html">
        Require all granted
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This wil route all subdomain requests to "D:\var\www\example\test\public_html" and all others to "D:\var\www\example\public_html"

Documentation can be found here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thanks, but no. My question is specific in that I need to be able to also have sub-domains that point to the main domain's document root.